# jQuery in Typescript: Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic<HTMLElement>'.ts

Tags: jquery, typescript

I use jQuery in typescript and want to add a smooth scroll. i get an error for the

> $.attr in jquery: Property 'attr' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'

How can I handle this error?

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: try `$(this).attr('href')` - not `$.attr`

Comment: the good thing is, there is no error in my typescript anymore. can you maybe also explain, why this works now? the bad thing is, there is still no smooth scroll. that doesnt work

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your markup, but this has a few examples of smooth scrolling with CSS and jQuery if that's what you're after. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Comment: i found the error. its not working in my case atm, because my anchors are like this <div id="/#anchor1">. i need the slash because i need to call the anchor from different pages. but with the slash the code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var offset = $(this).offset().top;

  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 500);
});
```

I think it should be something along these lines. I think what you were trying to do was to get the offset of the attribute, which is invalid:

`$(this).attr('href').offset // undefined`

You need to get the offset of the a element that was just clicked.

`$(this).offset().top`